# Find which element of one character vector another vector's elements start with

Tags: r

I have two character vectors:

```
v1 <- c("Red 1", "Red 2", "Red 3", "Blue thing", "Blue car", "Yellow anything")
v2 <- c("Yellow", "Red", "Blue")
```

I would like to get a vector, the length of v1, containing the index in v2 of the element that it starts with.

```
# Desired result
result <- c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1)
```

I have tried looking at some combination of `which()` and `startsWith()` but have not been able to vectorise the operation over both vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sapply` -

```
as.numeric(sapply(v1,function(x) which(sapply(v2,function(y) startsWith(x, y)))))

#[1] 2 2 2 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `outer` for efficiency

```
which(t(outer(v1, v2, FUN = function(x, y) startsWith(x, y))), arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]
[1] 2 2 2 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can try `gsub` + `match` like below

```
> match(gsub(sprintf("[^(%s)]", paste0(v2, collapse = "|")), "", v1), v2)
[1] 2 2 2 3 3 1
```

or

```
> match(gsub("\\s.*", "", v1), v2)
[1] 2 2 2 3 3 1
```